# How many label values can Prometheus manage?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have hundreds of customers and I have several metrics I'd like to keep to each one of them.

Let's say I have a metric `orders_count`.
I have two possibilities:

- use a label - i.e. `order_count{customer=customer_name}`
- have a different counter for every customer - i.e. `order_count_customer_name`

What is the preferable way and why?

Answer (score 6):

I definitely would not use the customer name as a label, since that would result in a high cardinality and therefore a huge amount of combinations, which will totally kill your prometheus performance.
I recommend reading this [post](https://www.robustperception.io/cardinality-is-key) for details.

Regarding your metric, not sure if makes sense to have one metric per client, but rather use metrics per e.g: operation, or action, to have an overview about you service behavior.

If you need to get reports about specific data, I would suggest using Grafana and a sql data source. Check [Grafana docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/) for details.

Comment: The thing is that I do want to track each client. Is Prometheus not the right tool for the job?

Comment: So I don't think that prometheus is the tool you want. Prometheus should be used to give an overview of the behaviour of your application, instead a report about your data.
Seems you are looking for a BI tool instead, that analyses your data content.

Comment: Can you suggest one?

Comment: I would suggest using Grafana and a sql data source. Check here https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/

Answer (score -3):

I would go with the first one;

```
order_count{customer=customer_name}
```

One way of looking at this could be - It is a more scalable approach as let's say in future you wish to add more labels say "customerLocation" too; and you can use any combination of labels to group your data.

Comment: Please don't do this. Prometheus specifically recommends against using high carinality in labels as each one makes creates its own time-series: https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/#labels

Comment: Exactly, I linked the blog post from Prometheus maintainers in my answer. https://www.robustperception.io/cardinality-is-key